# Include all files in a namespace

Tags: php, html, namespaces, autoload

I want import all file in a namespace by using ***use*** statement.
something like ***`use Vendor\Cart\* ;`***
I have psr-0 standard autoloader.
is there any possibility in standard PHP ?
suggestions will appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you can do that. However you CAN import the namespace itself to make referencing the class shorter. For example:

```
<?php
    namespace MyProject;
    use MyProject\Really\Long\Namespace\That\We\Want\All\Classes;

    class Test
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $instance1 = new Classes\Class1();
            $instance2 = new Classes\Class2();
            $instance3 = new Classes\Class3();
        }
    }
```